# A cyclic chain complex, contracting homotopy

Tags: homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

Hello I am trying to prove this

" Given a projective resolution of projectives

$P: \cdots\rightarrow P_{2}\rightarrow P_{1}\rightarrow P_{0} \rightarrow 0$

then $P$ is acyclic; i.e. $H_{n}(P)=0$ for $n>0$, if and only if the identity chain map $Id_{P}$ is a contracting map"

I proved the direction $(\Longleftarrow)$ however for the another direction I have the chain complex

$ \cdots\rightarrow P_{2}\rightarrow P_{1}\rightarrow P_{0} \rightarrow H_{0}(P) \rightarrow 0$

But I do not know how to start with the homotopy maps $S_{0}:P_{0}\rightarrow P_{1}$ in this case.

I only have that for the identity $1:H_{0}(P)\rightarrow H_{0}(P)$ we have chain map $f:P\rightarrow P$ inducing $1$  and it is unique up to homotopy.

From this I have that $f$ is homotopic to $Id_{P}$

Thank you for your time!

---------------Edit-------------

This one idea

Suppose that $H(P) = 0$. Then the maps $1$ and $0 : P \rightarrow P$
induce the same map – namely $φ = 0$ - on $H(P)$. By the comparison theorem we have that the two maps are homotopic

Is my argument correct?

Comment: What is your actual question? Are you asking if your proof is correct?

Comment: I only have some ideas however, I do not know how to proceed

Comment: Oh right my bad, I misread. Try and see that both $f$ and $0$ induce $1$ in homology and thus have to be chain homotopic since $f \simeq id_P \simeq 0 $.

Comment: Since $f\cong Id_{P}$ then, $H_{n}(f)=id_{H_{n}(P)}$ for all $n>0$. Since $H_{n}(P)=0$ for $n>0 $, it follows that $id_{H_{n}(P)}=0$. From this I do not see how $id_{P}\cong 0$.

Comment: I thought that an acyclic chain complex had $H_n(P) = 0$ for all $n$?